# Global Array in Excel Memory?

Tags: microsoft-excel, memory

I have a big sheet `Sheet1` in my Excel, using CSE I filtered it and generate an array in a range named `filtered_result` in `Sheet2`; `filtered_result` is afterwards used by many queries in `Sheet3` till `Sheet10`, mainly by `VLookUp` etc, everything works fine.

`filtered_result` in `Sheet2` is big and its computation is already slow, as an intermediate result it speeds up the computation in `Sheet3` till `Sheet10`.

Now, I'd like to o remove `Sheet2`, to avoid visualizing the intermediate result. This is still possible as I could modify the formula in `Sheet3` till `Sheet10`, but then the Excel becomes quite slow.

Is there any way to somehow store the original intermediate result `filtered_result` in `Sheet2` like something in the memory, and later queries will  still be able to retrieve it?

Comment: You might use a VBA global array - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654281/vba-public-array-how-to).

Comment: @harrymc but VBA global array can't be used in formula right?

Comment: The array can be assigned to a range via [Range.FormulaArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-formulaarray-property-excel), or maybe used in a formula via a defined user function call. If arrays are unsuitable and your problem is in just not visualizing sheet2, then just [hide it](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Hide-or-show-worksheets-or-workbooks-69f2701a-21f5-4186-87d7-341a8cf53344?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

Comment: The first thing coming to mind is simply hiding `Sheet2`, if your goal is just "avoid visualizing the intermediate result".

Comment: Hiding is a pretence...

Comment: I suggested hiding (and other solutions) and I think hiding is a practical solution. I don't see the difference between (1) a VBA global array which is invisible, and (2) a worksheet which is invisible. Except that option 1 is more sophisticated but also more complicated to create.

Comment: @harrymc I agree that hiding does solve the described problem, but I concede that it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @simlev: Well, hiding does fulfill the poster's demand : store in memory and be efficient on visualization. The only problem I see with it is that it's too simple, or not sophisticated enough to impress. The alternative is using VBA scripts and functions, whose components I can willingly point out, but are frankly too time-consuming for me to fully do here.

Comment: @harrymc I completely agree with your earlier comment: I'd use VBA but then why bother if hiding gives the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use array formulas, use regular formulas.

For example, let's say you have a formula that adds column B if the value in column A is greater than 10. Don't create an array formula with a conditional to do this. Instead make a new column C with the formula:

```
=If( $A > 10, $B, 0 )
```

So the third column contains either B's value if the condition is met or 0 if it is not met. Now just sum column C. This method is usually a lot faster than an array formula. It is called a "helper column".

If it is still slow to calculate, use macros or VBA to compute the values; that way you only have to compute them once, not recaculate them if things don't change. So, in the above example, instead of using the conditional formula, we can use a macro (or VBA code) to compute the If-formula and put the result in the cell. Then run the macro whenever you need to compute the table and generate values. With no conditionals (If-statements) in the spreadsheet itself, it will calculate much faster.

**How to Do Everything in Memory**

If you want to get rid of the sheet entirely, you can do everything in memory using static variables in a VBA code module:

```
Dim MyArray(1000, 2000) As Double

Sub computeMyArray()
   ... compute all the values of MyArray
End sub

Function GetValueFromMyArray( Dim x as Integer, Dim y as Integer )
   GetValueFromMyArray = MyArray( x, y )
End Function
```

You can then use this function in any cell of your workbook to get values out of the array you created which is memory. For example, a cell in your workbook could have the formula:

```
=GetValueFromMyArray( 5, 6 )
```

This would retrieve the 5th row, 6th of the array that is in memory.

Comment: yes i want to do everything in memory, thx.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and dumbest solution is just to hide the worksheet `Sheet2`
([link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Hide-or-show-worksheets-or-workbooks-69f2701a-21f5-4186-87d7-341a8cf53344?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)).

While this solution is not sophisticated, it does not require you to change
anything in your application and it will solve the slow display problem.

Answer (score 0):

This snipet should work without to much editing. Long story short, you are better of making a sub to make the array, and it should stay in memory as long as you call the sub again.

```
Public Sub MakeArrayGlobal(byRef Range as Range)
    dim MyPublicArray() as Variant
    with Range
        counter = 0
        For each cell in range
            MyPublicArray(counter) = cell.value #Or whatever you need
            counter = counter + 1
        Next
    End with
End sub
```

Comment: this is not good as every time have to call the sub again but the real computation is heavy.

Comment: @athos still is answering the question on the title. Also is faster that leaving volite formulas in the sheets.